# Wrapping content of a cell in table

Tags: html, css, text, html-table, word-wrap

I have a problem namely content of a cell goes out of this cell.
This is how it looks:

[image]

This is the code that i use to create this table:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="comments">
        <table class="table table-hover" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th class="col-md-2">Data</th>
                <th>Komentarz</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach ($loan->client->commentsChronologically as $comment) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-2"><?= $comment->add; ?></td>
                <td><?= $comment->content; ?></td> 
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
....
```

I suppose to modify this line:

```
<td><?= $comment->content; ?></td>
```

I tried to add wordwrap there, and I tried using word-wrap in the `<td>` but it just didn't work. I have no idea what should I do. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `<td><? print htmlentities($comment->content); ?></td>` if cell is broken by the content

Comment: Or try `<td><? print nl2br($comment->content); ?></td>` if you allow/save linebreaks in the comment content

Comment: Or with CSS `white-space: pre-wrap;`

Comment: Neither htmlentities or nl2br didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody is adressing the real issue, which is causing this: `table-layout: fixed` - remove that, and you're golden.

Comment: I added this to fix my problem. Without {table-layout: fixed} it didn't work as well. When i added it "Save" button appeared witch dissapeared when the text went out from a cell.

Comment: The fixed position is what is causing the problem. *shakes head*